# Calling variables from tkinter widgets and displaying them using a label, Python

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

New to Python. I'm trying to setup a GUI using tkinter.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

slider1 = Scale(root, from_=0, to=10, orient=HORIZONTAL, length=250)
slider1.grid()

p = slider1.get() * 30
totalP = p + 200

v = IntVar()

Label(root, textvariable=v, fg = "black", font = "Times ").grid()
def print_value():
    totalP = 200 + p
    v.set(totalP)


button = Button(root, text='Get Price', width=25, command=print_value)
button.grid()
```

I'm just trying to make it so that when I press the button it, it will grab the value that the slider is set to, multiply it by 30, add that to 200, then print it to a label, and if the slider value changes, then the button can be pressed again and the label will change. All help appreciated, and thank you very much!

Comment: You are grabbing the slider's value ONCE, before the user has had any chance to interact with it.  So, your print_value() function is going to set exactly the same label text every time you call it...

Comment: Ahhh! Thank you so much!